# Agregar a la URL actual la opción seleccionada de una lista desplegable

Tags: javascript

Yo cree un código que por ejemplo si estoy en la URL actual [www.dominio.com/?&filter_altura=180](http://www.dominio.com/?&filter_altura=180) y selecciono una opción de la lista me envía a la url [www.dominio.com/?&filter_color=rojo](http://www.dominio.com/?&filter_color=rojo).

Lo que yo necesito es que si estoy en la URL [www.dominio.com/?&filter_altura=180](http://www.dominio.com/?&filter_altura=180) y selecciono una opción de la lista me envie a la url [www.dominio.com/?&filter_altura=180?&filter_color=rojo](http://www.dominio.com/?&filter_altura=180?&filter_color=rojo).

Mi código hasta el momento es el siguiente

```
<select class="myselect">
  <option selected>Seleccionar Color</option>
  <option data-url="?&filter_color=rojo">Rojo</option>
  <option data-url="?&filter_color=amarillo">Amarillo</option>
  <option data-url="?&filter_color=azul">Azul</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>
const select = document.querySelector(".myselect");
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".myselect option");
 
// 1
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const url = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.url;
  if(url) {
    location.href = url;
  }
});
 
// 2
for(const option of options) {
  const url = option.dataset.url;
  if(location.href.includes(url)) {
    option.setAttribute("selected", "");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) para poder manipular sencillo la url y los parámetros. No se por qué agregaste una propiedad data a tus `select`, si tiene una propiedad `value` que puedes explotar. Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementarlo

```js
const color = document.querySelector('.color');
const altura = document.querySelector('.altura');
const url = new URL('http://www.dominio.com');

color.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
  url.searchParams.set('filter_color', this.value);
  console.log( url );
});

altura.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
  url.searchParams.set('filter_altura', this.value);
  console.log( url );
});
```

```html
<select class="color">
  <option selected>Seleccionar Color</option>
  <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
  <option value="amarillo">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="azul">Azul</option>
</select>


<select class="altura">
  <option selected>Seleccionar Color</option>
  <option value="180">180 metros</option>
  <option value="190">190 metros</option>
  <option value="200">200 metros</option>
</select>
```